# A movie about travelling to the future, where a man sees the earth "start" again?

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I can't remember the name of this movie I saw when I was a kid. All I can remember was that the man travelled through time every few years ahead, never coming back, one of the years the moon is quite close to the earth, another year everything is completely taken by nature and he meet a woman. In the middle it has robots, and when he comes back and everything is destroyed one of the robots that is on the floor remembers him.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds a lot like the [2002 version of The Time Machine](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0268695/).  In this case the ‘robot’ is the AI that personifies the New York Public Library.  The moon gets [slighly dented](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odrgDzciG6s) in the middle of the story.

Comment: That is exactly the movie I was talking about, I just watched again. You are amazing for knowing the movie with such bad description. Thank you.